# パイプの両辺を入れ替えて書きたい

Tags: bash, shellscript

パイプ(`|`)の両辺を逆にして書けるような方法はありますか？
うっかり「標準入力を受け取る側のコマンドの呼出し」から書いてしまった場合に、先頭に戻らずにそのまま続けたいのです。
そのため
`<受け取る側コマンド呼出し> <標準出力するコマンド呼出しを含む何か>`
という形をした記法を探しています。
理想的なのは
`<受け取る側コマンド呼出し> <何か> <標準出力するコマンド呼出し>`
です。
とりあえず思いついたのは、リダイレクトとプロセス置換を使う方法です。

```
$ ps -e | grep avahi -
  876 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
 1016 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
$ grep avahi - < <(ps -e)
  876 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
 1016 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
```

これよりコンパクト（タイプ数が少ない、2つ以上の機能を組み合わせていない等）な記法が有れば教えてください。

Comment: タイプ数は変わりませんが、bash の `here string` を使って `grep avahi <<< "$(ps -e)"` とか。

Comment: なぜそのようなことをしたいのでしょうか?  bash を使っているのであれ
ば、先頭に戻って出力コマンドをタイプするのは造作もないことではないでしょうか。

Comment: @yaegashi おっしゃる通りで、普段は`Ctrl-a`,`Ctrl-e`で往復してます。質問自体は単純な興味から発したもので、実用的なものがあればと思い質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 1):

先に記述したコマンドが引数に指定したファイル名を読み込むのであれば、リダイレクトする必要はないですね。例に挙がっている `grep` であれば次のように書けます。

```
$ grep avahi <(ps -e)
```